# Is the set $A_i$, $i = 1,2,3$ connected in the space $C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $A_1 = \{x:x(0)<0, x(1)>1\}$, $A_2 = \{x:x(t)\in \mathbb Q,\forall t \in [0,1]\} $, and $A_3 = \mathbb P_1[0,1]$, the set of all polynomials of at most $1^{\text{st}}$ degree on $[0,1]$.

Is the set $A_i$, $i = 1,2,3$ connected in the space $C[0,1]$?

For the solution, I think this definition is proper: $A_i$ is disconnected if $A_i = A_{i1} \cup A_{i2}$ for  $A_{i1},\  A_{i2}$ are separated sets and nonempty. Connected otherwise.

But I don't exactly know how to show whether they are connected or disconnected by following this definition.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Are you asked about each of $A_i$, $i=1,2,3$, whether it's connected in $C[0,1]$ or not? That's how the question in your second paragraph sounds, which makes it three separate questions (exercises). But in that case, forming the union $A=A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3$ has nothing to do with the question. Or are you asked just one question whether this union $A=A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3$ is connected? Please clarify.

Comment: @zipirovich I think I misunderstood the question and thought asking if union is connected. I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to your solution, I think you misunderstood the question. The question seems to ask whether each $A_i$, *individually*, is connected. Not if they form a separation of whatever is $A$.

Now, addressing the question itself: $A_1$ is convex. $A_3$ is also convex, but it is even a subspace. $A_2$ on the other hand is separated in very much the same way as $\mathbb{Q}$: rigorously, the sets $U^{<\sqrt{2}} \cap A_2$ and $U^{>\sqrt{2}} \cap A_2$ form a separation of $A_2$, where
$$U^{<\sqrt{2}}:=\{x \mid x(1/2)< \sqrt{2}\}$$
and $U^{>\sqrt{2}}$ is defined analogously. You only need to prove that both are open.